# Facebook like on click

Tags: facebook, xhtml

Is there a way to have a user "like" on Facebook by clicking a URL, so it opens the site to you liking it ( obv if the user is signed in already ). Is it a matter of submitting POST data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if this were possible we'd already have a deluge of sites doing it, for some reason, some companies REALLY want you to like them on Facebook...